# How to enable sudo password?

Tags: password, sudo

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a virtual machine in the Windows Azure Cluster.

By default `sudo` is not requiring a password.

I would like to force a password on all `sudo` commands.

How do I go about making this change?

Here is the content of the `visudo`:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults env_reset
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults timestamp_timeout=0

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Which symbol $(this means user) or #(this means root user) do you see in your terminal.

Answer (score 8):

I was confused at first. Later I found the configuration in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`.

```
# Created by cloud-init v. 0.7.5 on Tue, 16 Sep 2014 14:34:31 +0000

# User rules for azureuser
azureuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment the last line will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AWS instances are setup in the same way. I don't know what the username is on Ubuntu instances in Azure, but you will need to go into your `/etc/sudoers` file and look for the following line:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Replace `NOPASSWD` with `PASSWD` and save the file.

Comment: That line doesn't exist in the sudoers file I have updated the question with the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the file `/etc/sudoers.d/99-bitnami` that included the `NOPASSWD` line. I removed `NOPASSWD:` so that the file now looks like this:

```
%bitnami-admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

It should have the same effect in your case to remove `NOPASSWD:` in your `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` [¹](https://askubuntu.com/a/525681/1195912)